# Form of Renormalized Fermion Propagator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, propagator

I am calculating a fermionic loop and the expression I obtained for the loop has the form $\not{p}Σ_1(p^2)+Σ_2(p^2)$. Here, $Σ_1$ and $Σ_2$ both have real and imaginary parts. The propagator then becomes

$$\frac{iZ(\not{p}+M)}{p^2−M^2}$$

where $Z=(1−Σ_1)^{−1}$ and $M=(M_0+Σ_2)Z$, $M_0$ being the bare mass. After imposing the conditions for the pole to be at $p=M$ and for the residue to be unity there, I obtained the following conditions on the functions and their derivatives.
$$M\Sigma_1(M^2)+\Sigma_2(M^2)=0$$
$$M\Sigma'_1(M^2)+\Sigma'_2(M^2)=\frac{-\Sigma_1(M^2)}{2M}=\frac{\Sigma_2(M^2)}{2M^2}$$
Now, I know that one way of satisfying these two conditions is to use the on-shell condition and require $\Sigma_i(M^2)=0$, $\Sigma'_i(M^2)=0$, $i=1,2$. But if I want to use the more general conditions obtained above an still write an expression for the renormalized propagator? I can't expand in powers of $(\not{p}-M)$ because I want to plot the propagator and I wouldn't know how to plot a function of $\not{p}$. I was trying to expand both $\Sigma$'s as
$$\Sigma_i=\Sigma_i(p^2)-\Sigma_i(M^2)+(p^2-M^2)\Sigma_i'(p^2)|_{p^2=M^2}$$
but I am not sure that this works, as $\Sigma_1$ is still multiplied by a $\not{p}$. Is there a way out of this conundrum? Thanks.